# How to add variables to appender in log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, appender

is there way to add variables from code to appender?
e.g. `<param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO logs(name,log,log_lvl,log_date) VALUES(" + myClass.getUser().getName() +",'%m','%p','%d')"/>`

Comment: Your configuration snippet comes from a Log4j 1.x XML configuration. Are you using Log4j 1.x or Log4j 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to configure Log4j2 with Java code. Check out [Programmatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html). It also covers configuring appenders, which is the level at which you can define the appender's sql parameter if you so wish.